# Webhook + Server-side Authentication

Tags: podio

I have a user provide me the organization he wants to Sync with our system. We create the hooks afterwards for each App of the Organization.

The only workaround I found is to ask for each App ID and Token or the username authentication.

How can a Webhook be authentified to have the right to get items from all Apps at the same time? (like a server-side authentication)

Comment: We need an organization authentification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options: The best is to contact Podio support and get an increased trust level for your API key. Then app tokens can be retrieved through the API and you can fully automate hook creation.

The alternative is to create a user that's a member of all spaces which you can authenticate as using password-based authentication.

Comment: Podio Support told me to post my question about how to get a higher trust level key on the dev forum. I'll do so but I don't make a connection.

Comment: Podio Support told you something wrong. I'll make sure to grab your ticket now.